# member cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Tags: c#

In my program I got an error that "Member 'TestUno.Form1.value' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead  C:\Users\ADL65654\Documents\Visual Studio". I want to access static array from form1 to form3.

```
form3:   
            byte by1;
            by = ((Form1)this.Owner).value[0]; //Error
form1:
           public static byte[] value = new byte[10];
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `by = Form1.value[0]` - that is what compiler is asking for

Comment: You are making the array but are you actually filling it somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You have made the variable `static`. That means all instances of your Form1 class *share* a *single* array. There is no such thing as *the* array of *the* Form1 instance you have in `this.Owner`.

You can either access the shared instance of the array by ignoring the instance in `this.Owner` and using `Form1.value[0]` or you have to remove the `static` keyword if every Form1 instance should have it's own value array.